# Build gcc for running on arm

Tags: gcc, arm, gnu-toolchain

I have some issue with Linaro gcc. Durig build arm image gcc package was included. But as result gcc command work but there are no headers and no crtl1.o.

Could someone suggest me how build image with full working gcc toolchain for arm.
P.S. I don't need crossplatform compiler on linux target. It should be working gcc on arm platform (on board).

Comment: You may had problems installing the package, it could be a path/sysroot issue. There should be enough pointers on the web to help you compile gcc for a different architecture.

Comment: I also tried to compile gcc for arm-native, On target while compiling hello.c code i also faced same issue later i resolved that issue then i got stuck while linking and including library, I guess while building U missed something. If share your configuration details then i may help.